# How to use variables in a range from 1 to 200 in loop on bash

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, loops, seq

I have script for getting some records:

```
#!/bin/bash 

host_start=test
domain=test.com

for host in "${host_start}"{1..200}."$domain";
do
    address=`dig +short $host`
    echo "$address = $host"
done
```

In this case, everything is OK. I have:

```
192.168.1.1 = test1.test.com
192.168.1.2 = test2.test.com
192.168.1.3 = test3.test.com
...
...
...
etc ...
```

But instead of the literal `{1..200}`, I want to use variables in the start of my script. I did this:

```
t1=1
t2=200
for host in "${host_start}"{$t1..$t2}."$domain";
do 
...
```

In this case, I get an error:

```
dig: 'test{1..200}.test.com' is not a legal name (empty label)
```

Where is my error? How do I fix it?

Comment: @chepner I marked the one your dupe as a dupe of my dupe, if you want to hammer that one too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Brace expansion happens before variable expansion, so you can't use it with variables. Use a loop or the `seq` command.

```
for ((i=t1; i<=t2; i++)) ; do
    host=$host_start$i.$domain
```

or

```
for i in $( seq $t1 $t2 ) ; do
    host=$host_start$i.$domain
```

Comment: @MadPhysicist: `seq` is a nonstandard utility, so if strict POSIX compliance is a must, it should be avoided; it is, however, both widely available, widely used, and continues to provide useful functionality.

Comment: Fair enough. Comment rescinded.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably do:

```
for ((i=t1; i <= t2; i++)); do 
   host="${host_start}"$i."$domain"
   ...
done
```